# how can i make a javascript based form checkbox validate with javascript before sending my form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, checkbox

Hi i have a contact form on my site, In this form i got a javascript checkbox button.

This is the end code of my form: this div tag is my checkbox:

```
<p><label for="agree">(*) I agree whit the transport terms and conditions:</label><div id="cb"></div></p>
<p>hi
<input name="Submit / Send" type="submit" class="submit" id="Submit / Send" tabindex="370" value="Submit / Send" />
<p id="error_zone" style="visibility:hidden;">Errors: There are some errors in the form. Please correct them.</p>
</p>
```

This is the javascript text button:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var cbh = document.getElementById('cb');
    var val = '1';
    var cap = '';

    var cb = document.createElement('input');
    cb.type = 'checkbox';
    cbh.appendChild(cb);
    cb.name = val;
    cb.value = cap;
    cbh.appendChild(document.createTextNode(cap));
</script>
```

also i make use of spry validation for my other form elements.
I would like to validate the checkbox with javascript to create a captcha checkbox!
Is it posible to let pop up a validation masage and and not disturbe the spry validation?!
Its important that if javascript is turned off the form als can't submit any more.

Hope someone can help me. thanx alot for your time!

i'm trying to encomplish this: http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-checkbox-captcha-wins/

snippet of spry validation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var errorsOnSubmit = function(form){
 var ret = Spry.Widget.Form.validate(form);
 var errorZone= document.getElementById('error_zone');
 if (!ret){
      errorZone.style.visibility = 'visible';
      errorZone.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
 }else{
      errorZone.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
 return ret;
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var spryselect1 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect("spryselect1", {isRequired:false,  invalidValue:"1", validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
var spryselect2 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect("spryselect2", {isRequired:false, invalidValue:"1", validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
var spryselect3 = new Spry.Widget.ValidationSelect("spryselect3", {isRequired:false, invalidValue:"1", validateOn:["blur", "change"]});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give an ID to the checkbox after you created the element

```
cb.type = 'checkbox';
cb.id = 'mycheckbox';
cbh.appendChild(cb);
```

Now, you can select the element using `document.getElementById('mycheckbox')` and the validate it.

Here is a snippet to validate the checkbox

```
var myform = document.forms("yourformname");
myform.onsubmit = function() {

    //validate the checkbox
    var checkb = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
    if(checkb.checked != true) { 
       alert('not checked');
    }

    //rest of the validation
};
```

#### Update 1:

Haven't tested but should work

```
var errorsOnSubmit = function(form){

  //validate the checkbox
  var checkb = document.getElementById('mycheckbox');
  if(checkb.checked != true) { 
     alert('not checked');
  }

 var ret = Spry.Widget.Form.validate(form);
 var errorZone= document.getElementById('error_zone');
 if (!ret){
      errorZone.style.visibility = 'visible';
      errorZone.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
 }else{
      errorZone.style.visibility = 'hidden';
 }
 return ret;
}
```

Comment: thank you! but how can i make a validation function? sorry i realy suck in javascript is this right?: function checkform()
{
 if (!document.mycheckbox.checked) {
 // box is not checked
 return false;
}

Comment: that's working but pops up when i open the page in my localhost if it is possible to tjeks that script when submitted the form whit the submit button and tell the form he can only submit when javascript is enabled i got my checkbox captcha working?

Comment: i try to and this to the code:  frm.onsubmit = cb_it; but it won't work do you know what i'm doing wrong thanks alot for your help your awesome!!

Comment: @phj, may be my update will help to understand the whole thing

Comment: Nice this works perfect i understand it a little bit more now, But i got a problem now with my spry validation on the rest of the form elements the submit button only validates the checkbox and not the spry scripts any more, i have tried to put the spry scripts on the place of the (//rest of the validation) in the script bit this wont work out. do you have any idee how i can fix this? thanks alot! *(i put a snippet of my spry script(s) in question box above.

Comment: @phj, Check my update again, but I haven't used spry, so i am not sure

Comment: @phj, You are right, you cannot rely on javascript completely. The validation which you applied using javascript has be replicated on your serverside script as well, this way, you provide usability feature using javascript and using server side validation as well, you made sure it is validated throughout.

Comment: @phj, Thanks for the offer at paypal, thats so sweet of you.

Comment: Hi i have send you a e-mail tanx!

Answer (score 0):

u can try this code

```
function agree() {
if (document.getElementById("cb").checked){
alert("checked");
document.getElementById("Send").setAttribute(disabled,"false");
document.getElementById(seny).
}else{
alert("unchecked");
document.getElementById("Send").disabled="true";
}
}

<p>
            <input type="checkbox" id="cb" onclick="javascript:agree();">
            <label for="agree">
                (*) I agree whit the transport terms and conditions:
            </label>
        </p>
        <p id="seny">
            <input disabled="disabled" name="Send" type="submit" class="submit"
                id="Send" tabindex="370" value="Submit / Send" />
        </p>
```

Comment: i don't think this will work out and a spam bot can also fill in the chekbox i would like to encomplish this: http://uxmovement.com/forms/captchas-vs-spambots-why-the-checkbox-captcha-wins/